# Weighted Kmeans R

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to do a Kmeans clustering on a dataset (namely, Sample_Data) with three variables (columns) such as below:

```
     A  B  C
1    12 10 1
2    8  11 2
3    14 10 1
.    .   .  .
.    .   .  .
.    .   .  .
```

in a typical way, after scaling the columns, and determining the number of clusters, I will use this function in R:

```
Sample_Data <- scale(Sample_Data)
output_kmeans <- kmeans(Sample_Data, centers = 5, nstart = 50)
```

But, what if there is a preference for the variables? I mean that, suppose variable (column) A, is more important than the two other variables?
how can I insert their weights in the model?
Thank you all

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and the answer here is not satisfying for me.

What we both wanted was an observation-weighted k-means clustering in R. A good readable example for our question is this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-the-us-population-observation-weighted-k-means-f4d58b370002

However the solution to use the flexclust package is not satisfying simply b/c the used algorithm is not the "standard" k-means algorithm but the "hard competitive learning" algorithm. The difference are well described above and in the package description.

I looked through many sites and did not find any solution/package in R in order to use to perform a "standard" k-means algorithm with weighted observations. I was also wondering why the flexclust package explicitly do not support weights with the standard k-means algorithm. If anyone has an explanation for this, please feel free to share!

So basically you have two options: First, rewrite the flexclust-algorithm to enable weights within the standard approach. Or second, you can estimate weighted cluster centroids as starting centroids and perform a standard k-means algorithm with only one iteration, then compute new weighted cluster centroids and perform a k-means with one iteration and so on until you reach convergence.

I used the second alternative b/c it was the easier way for me. I used the data.table package, hope you are familiar with it.

```
rm(list=ls())

library(data.table)

### gen dataset with sample-weights
dataset     <- data.table(iris)
dataset[, weights:= rep(c(1, 0.7, 0.3, 4, 5),30)] 
dataset[, Species := NULL]


### initial hclust for estimating weighted centroids
clustering    <- hclust(dist(dataset[, c(1:4)], method = 'euclidean'), 
                        method = 'ward.D2')
no_of_clusters <- 4


### estimating starting centroids (weighted)
weighted_centroids  <- matrix(NA, nrow = no_of_clusters, 
                              ncol =  ncol(dataset[, c(1:4)]))
for (i in (1:no_of_clusters))
{
 weighted_centroids[i,] <- sapply(dataset[, c(1:4)][cutree(clustering, k = 
                                                    no_of_clusters) == i,], weighted.mean, w = dataset[cutree(clustering, k = no_of_clusters) == i, weights])
 }


### performing weighted k-means as explained in my post
iter            <- 0 
cluster_i       <- 0
cluster_iminus1 <- 1

## while loop: if number of iteration is smaller than 50 and cluster_i (result of 
## current iteration) is not identical to cluster_iminus1 (result of former 
## iteration) then continue
while(identical(cluster_i, cluster_iminus1) == F && iter < 50){

  # update iteration  
  iter <- iter + 1

  # k-means with weighted centroids and one iteration (may generate warning messages 
  # as no convergence is reached)
  cluster_kmeans <- kmeans(x = dataset[, c(1:4)], centers = weighted_centroids, iter = 1)$cluster

  # estimating new weighted centroids
  weighted_centroids <- matrix(NA, nrow = no_of_clusters, 
                               ncol=ncol(dataset[,c(1:4)]))
  for (i in (1:no_of_clusters))
{
 weighted_centroids[i,] <- sapply(dataset[, c(1:4)][cutree(clustering, k = 
                                                    no_of_clusters) == i,], weighted.mean, w = dataset[cutree(clustering, k = no_of_clusters) == i, weights])
 }

  # update cluster_i and cluster_iminus1
  if(iter == 1) {cluster_iminus1 <- 0} else{cluster_iminus1 <- cluster_i}
  cluster_i <- cluster_kmeans

}


## merge final clusters to data table
dataset[, cluster := cluster_i]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a kmeans weighted clustering, like the one presented in `flexclust` package:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexclust/flexclust.pdf

The function

```
cclust(x, k, dist = "euclidean", method = "kmeans",
weights=NULL, control=NULL, group=NULL, simple=FALSE,
save.data=FALSE)
```

Perform k-means clustering, hard competitive learning or neural gas on a data matrix.
`weights` An optional vector of weights to be used in the fitting process. Works only in combination with hard competitive learning.

A toy example using iris data:

```
library(flexclust)
data(iris)
cl <- cclust(iris[,-5], k=3, save.data=TRUE,weights =c(1,0.5,1,0.1),method="hardcl")
cl  
    kcca object of family ‘kmeans’ 

    call:
    cclust(x = iris[, -5], k = 3, method = "hardcl", weights = c(1, 0.5, 1, 0.1), save.data = TRUE)

    cluster sizes:

     1  2  3 
    50 59 41
```

As you can see from the output of cclust, also using competitive learning the family is always kmenas. 
The difference is related to cluster assignment during training phase:

> If method is "kmeans", the classic kmeans algorithm as given by
>   MacQueen (1967) is used, which works by repeatedly moving all cluster
>   centers to the mean of their respective Voronoi sets. If "hardcl",
>   on-line updates are used (AKA hard competitive learning), which work
>   by randomly drawing an observation from x and moving the closest
>   center towards that point (e.g., Ripley 1996).

The `weights` parameter is just a sequence of numbers, in general I use number between 0.01 (minimum weight) and 1 (maximum weight).

Comment: Thanks, But it mentioned that, weights, only works in hard Competitive Learning. Is it the same as Kmeans?
and do you happen to know the manual format of inserting weights into the model?for Example, in weighted means, we can use a command in R for it, or we can manually do the math.
do you know the logic behind inserting weights into kmeans model?

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, and explanation.
as the last question (hopefully), is there any constraint on the weights?such as sum (weights)=1 or anything?
can you introduce a reference to me to study more on allocating weights to the variables?

Comment: There is no constraint in this function on the weights. You can find an application here: https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-the-us-population-observation-weighted-k-means-f4d58b370002

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the weight of a variable (column), just multiply it with a constant c > 1.

It's trivial to show that this increases the weight in the SSQ optimization objective.

Comment: Thank you.
at what stage this should be done?
after scale or before scale?
can you name a reference?

Comment: Scaling = weighting. So do not blindly apply some random scaling function you found in some example. Instead choose appropriate weights. No reference for this, it is just obvious from the objective function that you need to choose appropriate scales for each attribute.

Comment: say we have three variables:
monetary value(ranges between 1000 to 10^6)
Frequency (ranges between 1 to 10 )
latency (ranges between 1 to 250)
and you believe I should not scale them?
or what is the method to find the appropriate scales?

Comment: If you want to weight them, scaling is redundant. Just choose smaller weights for the variables that would otherwise dominate the result. But do this in a smart way. There is no benefit in first scaling them to [0;1], that is just doing things twice. Note that usually, when you have axes of such different scale, the result will be quite useless answay. The SSQ objective usually lacks any real relevancy, and your clustering optimizes a useless quantity then.

Comment: I believe I have to study more. by the way thank you for the help

Comment: for example use pca's proportion of variance as a weight and multiply the pca values by this. ex summary(relevant_tsfeature_tbl_pca)$importance[2,]