# How to weight a set of variables for k-means or PAM clustering?

Tags: r, variables, cluster-analysis, k-means, weighted

I want to do clustering based on 140 variables.The first 6 variables are more important than the rest 134. So I planned to weight all the variables, with the first 6 weighted "1" and others weighted "0.5".

I got some information here: [Weighted Kmeans R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901178/weighted-kmeans-r)

The accepted answer suggested a flexclust package to do weighted k-means clustering, and used the iris dataset to show an example. Like this:

```
library(flexclust)
data(iris)
cl <- cclust(iris[,-5], k=3, save.data=TRUE,weights 
=c(1,0.5,1,0.1),method="hardcl")
cl  
kcca object of family ‘kmeans’ 

call:
cclust(x = iris[, -5], k = 3, method = "hardcl", weights = c(1, 
0.5, 1, 0.1), save.data = TRUE)

cluster sizes:

 1  2  3 
50 59 41
```

My main doubt is that my dataset have too many variables, I can't weight all of them with codes like weights = c(1, 0.5, 1, 0.1). Is there any other ideas that I can weight a set of variables at the same time? Is the weighted variables work in PAM as well?

Comment: By the way, the first 6 variables actually have larger and wider values than the other variables. If I don't scale the dataset, does it perform the same effect as I assigned more weight on the first 6 variables? Is that sound reasonable?

Comment: I would recommend scaling the dataset, not scaling will probably have unpredictable effects as it depends how big the scale difference is and what distance metric you're using for kmeans.

Comment: @Marius Which kind of scaling would you recommend me to use? After the normal scale() scaling I found that my dataset becomes not clusterable (e.g. the elbow plot shows no "elbow" when defining number of clusters)

Comment: If they have very different scales, does the sum-of-squares error measure make any sense at all?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Sorry I don't really understand your question, what do you mean by "different scales?"

Comment: Each variable likely has a different meaning. Are they comparable? One reason why people resort to standardization is because it often makes different attributes a little bit more comparable. For example, temperatue in F and in C will be mapped to the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to generate the 140 weights so the first 6 variables are weighted higher, you can do:

```
weights = rep(c(1, 0.5), c(6, 134))
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete! I think the answer must discuss the tradeoff's between balancing and not balancing the data on clustering with suitable examples. Suggest to elaborate your perspective further

Comment: @mnm: this is Stack Overflow, it's about coding questions, not statistics/machine learning. I'm trying to answer the specific coding question asked by the OP, not give an in-depth tutorial on how to run a perfect k-means analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very basic questions but it stuck me.

Comment: @mnm: if you think there's an issue with this answer, and the more general issue of not providing in-depth stats tutorials every time you answer a coding question, feel free to raise the issue on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Marius and I think what you have posted does not qualify to be an answer at least in its present state. I have no time to discuss it on Meta.