# Is there an algorithm that can be clustered with weights?

Tags: r, algorithm, cluster-analysis

```
     X           Y      Flow
35.829875   128.550225  0.66
35.64903952 128.4373915 2.36
35.87826747 128.6094381 2.09
35.83962222 128.5711917 0.77
35.94296667 128.5503917 3.99
35.94184918 128.5629876 5.86
35.87022926 128.6917042 4.13
35.84118463 128.610549  16.61
35.84861677 128.6244008 0.04
35.86461772 128.595875  0
```

The above data is part of the floating population data. 
'X' and 'Y' are latitude and longitude, and 'Flow' represent the number of floating populations.
We want to cluster the X and Y variables by weight based on  Flow, and then find the center point.
Is this possible?

- I initially wanted to create multiple clusters using k means.
  I wonder if the Flow variable can affect the clustering of two variables without changing the values ​​of X and Y. I want a number of center points.
  My explanation is lacking because I am a beginner to analysis. Please understand.

Comment: You first need to decide how do you want to cluster your value. You be able to create a new column specifying the clusters. You can then calculate the barycentre or centroid for each cluster easily : https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6025/133495

Comment: @tom   At first I wanted to find the center point by kmeans the coordinates. But now I want to find the center point by weighting the coordinates as much as the Flow variable. Can I solve this with the solution you gave me? In fact I did not understand well.

Comment: So your don't need to make clusters anymore, just one center for weighted coordinates?

Comment: Do you mean `c(sum(X * Flow), sum(Y * Flow)) / sum(Flow)` ?

Comment: @tom  Please check the changed post. sorry to bother you.

Comment: @user31264 Please check the changed post. sorry to bother you.

Comment: I think you need to get some understanding on what king of clustering you want to do. I would advise you this document to understand the difference between geographic clustering, with or without accounting for the value of the points (weight). https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=2ahUKEwjB1enkrajkAhUNbBoKHfD9ChsQFjAHegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfs.semanticscholar.org%2F6acd%2Fd7fc0a181d5cafd029b00bfa5a97e00e9425.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Ji2aL3TCSRTVDKD8qEg-Q

Comment: Just a summary: I believe you have your answer in the `X * Flow` comment.  First, you determine your clusters.  Then, for each cluster, you determine the weighted centroid as @user31264 described.  I believe that solves the question you described.

Comment: Maybe you need this question about weighted clustering in R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901178/weighted-kmeans-r

Comment: @tom  The solution you presented seems to solve my question. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Most clustering algorithms can easily be weighted.

- in k-means, use the weighted mean
- in hierarchical clustering you already use weights, they are initially 1 - just set them differently
- in DBSCAN, use the sun of weights instead of the count for finding core points
- many more

But few libraries have support for this, you will need to write your own code.